# Две резиновые колонки

Tags: css

Всем привет, у меня есть div, ширина которого относительно известна (пусть будет 90%), а в нем нужно расположить еще два дива горизонтально (в строчку) так, чтобы ширина левого дива зависела от его содержимого, а правый заполнял всю оставшуюся часть. Нагуглить такое не удается, а сам я не справляюсь. Помогите пожалуйста кто чем может!

Comment: Обязательно div? Просто можно попробовать с таблицей.
Еще слышал о display:flex, но не могу ничего сказать, так как руки не дошли пощупать это новшество самому.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, правило float: left; для левого дива решит ваши проблемы.